# WhatsApp apk download

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a new phone, want WhatsApp, but don't want to share data with Facebook.

I am hoping i might be able to get an old apk (Trojan and virus free) that I could install in the hope of being given the option to opt out when I upgrade it.

Does anyone know if any of the many apk sites online are legit?

Comment: The thing is, that WhatsApp forces their users to update after a fixed amount of time. Even if you found an old APK, you'd have to forcibly update in a handful of months.

Answer (score 0):

apkmirror.com is legit. It's run by Android police